# How to get value of multiple values field in Drupal 8?

Tags: drupal-8

I have multiple values image field in Drupal 8 and I would like to prepare values in Controller for output in the twig template.

It's simple (well, if we can call the ridiculously complicated *"lets-do-everything-in-OOP-eventhough-its-useless"* Drupal 8 way simple) for single value fields:

```
$nids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')->condition('type', 'zbornik_a_foto')->execute();
$nodes = Node::loadMultiple($nids);

$data = array();
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
  $data[] = array(
    'rocnik' => $node->get('field_rok')->getValue(),
    'miesto' => $node->get('field_miesto_konania')->getValue(),
    'fotografie' => $node->get('field_zbornik')->getValue(),
    'foto' => $node->get('field_fotografie')->getValue(),
  );
}

return array(
  '#theme' => 'riadky_zazili',
  '#data' => $data,
  '#title' => 'Zažili sme',
);
```

However, the `field_fotografie` value is multiple values field and I would like to get all image's URIs in the `$data` array. Does anybody know how? Ideally less than 10 lines of useless OOP jibber-jabber. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Try like this way, it might be useful for you.

```
$data = array();
foreach($nodes as $node) {
  $photo = array();
  foreach($node->get('field_image')->getValue() as $file){
    $fid = $file['target_id']; // get file fid;
    $photo[] = \Drupal\file\Entity\File::load($fid)->getFileUri();
  }

  $data[] = array(
    'rocnik' => $node->get('field_rok')->getValue(),
    'miesto' => $node->get('field_miesto_konania')->getValue(),
    'fotografie' => $node->get('field_zbornik')->getValue(),
    'foto' => $photo,
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$nids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')->condition('type', 'zbornik_a_foto')->execute();
$nodes = Node::loadMultiple($nids);

$data = array();
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
  $fotoValues = $node->get('field_fotografie')->getValue();
  $myvalues  = array();
  foreach($fotoValues as $val){
    $myvalues[] = $val["value"];
  }
  $data[] = array(
    'rocnik' => $node->get('field_rok')->getValue(),
    'miesto' => $node->get('field_miesto_konania')->getValue(),
    'fotografie' => $node->get('field_zbornik')->getValue(),
    'foto' => $myvalues,
  );
}

return array(
  '#theme' => 'riadky_zazili',
  '#data' => $data,
  '#title' => 'Zažili sme',
);
```

Hope this helps you 
thanks